# Array AJAX acting fishy

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, jquery-ui

I have some AJAX code that uses a little bit of JQUERY and also tries to use javascript to define the array that gets sent over POST to update_DBO.php

I've got the script here...

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
            update: function(event, ui) {

        var fruitOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
        var fruitnumbers = fruitOrder.replace(/[,]/g, ""); 
        var fruitarray = fruitnumbers.split("");

    jQuery.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "update_DBO.php",
     data:  { fruitarray : fruitarray },
     cache: false,
     success: function(response)
        {   
            alert(fruitarray);  
            $('#sortable1').addClass('greenbg', 350, 'linear').delay(50);
            $('#sortable1').removeClass('greenbg', 1200, 'linear').delay(50);
            document.write('fruit: ');
            document.write(fruitarray);
        }
    });
   }
 });
});
 </script>
```

So.

The problem is that it does not seem to either calculate anything at all for fruit fruitarrary OR it doesn't pass it or document.write it. It just seems to come up null

Any help solving this puzzle is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't use `document.write` like that. It can only be used when the page is first loading, not asynchronously. If this is for debugging, use `console.log()` and view the result in the JavaScript console. You can also use that instead of `alert()` for debugging.
2. You make an AJAX call but don't do anything with the result which is in the `response` parameter.
3. Does it get to your `alert()` at all?
4. What is `.addClass( 'greenbg', 350, 'linear' )` supposed to do? It sounds like you mean to use `.animate()` here. If it's a kind of color-changing effect, note that you'd need to animate with actual color values, something that the animation engine can interpolate toward. What would it even mean to add a classname linearly over a time period? Add the class a letter at a time? :-)
5. The `.delay()` calls won't do anything. They only affect the animation queue. If you use `.animate()` you can use `.delay()` with it, but I would put all the related calls in a single chain.
6. Do you know how to use the JavaScript debugger? If not, it's time to start. My favorite is in Chrome; here's an [introduction to the Chrome developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/).

Answer (score 0):

ok, where to start.  We are lacking a bit of context.  So I am using your code structure to help me figure this out.

First, please use propper tabbing/spacing when writing code.  It makes life so much easier for the rest of us.

Thats all for that.

Lets get down to figuring our your issue.

1) use a javascript debugger of somekind.  firebug for firefox, chrome developer tools for chrome, even IE has something.  (better to use firebug though).

2) figure out if anything is being populated in the fruitOrder variable.  It might not.

3) why are you doing a regex replace.  I have no idea what you are attepting there.  It seems your taking all the commas and replacing them with an empty string.  ANd then you're attempting to split on an empty string.  I would a) get rid of the replace and b) do your string split on the comma instead.

4) the ajax call you're using the old pattern (at least what i know of it).  You might want to consider using a deffered pattern.  It seems to be the new hotness.

Something like this

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url : urlHere,
    data : {data: data},
    type : 'post'
});

request.done(function(response){
    // do something with the response
});

request.fail(function(response){
    // something horrible happened.  You got a server error response.
});
```

5) I dont think you're using the document.write correctly.  You might want to use something else like an alert to see if something happens.  You could use an alert or a console.log().  don't leave the console.log code in though. it breaks on IE without sufficient checks or tweaks.

I hope that helps